# Google disapproved Ads due to malware, but no malware in site?

Tags: google

We have a number of ad's running with Google and have had them for a long time, but now they have been disapproved due to malware detection. Google said they can find reference to (pushlaram[.]com), every trace of this has been removed from the site and - 
- Search console is showing no issues or security issues 
- stop badware is coming up clear
- all developer searched of the site, files & event transient files are clean
- the padlock is there and the site is https and showing secure when you go to the site on google.

When I call the helpline, they are still refusing o put the ad's live saying the site still has this domain in it, but they won't tell me where or give me any other information. Has anyone ever come across this problem before or have any idea on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I might have misunderstood: are Google are saying that your WordPress site has links to pushlaram, or your AdWords adverts? if it's the site, I suggest you get a backup of your database as XML or SQL, i.e. text that you can read, and search it for pushlaram; and get filesystem access to your site, or download absolutely everything, and search that with grep for any references to pushlaram in the files. I'm surprised Google are being unhelpful, though: the more specific they can be the quicker you can fix this.

Comment: That is the problem, me and a developer have looked through the site, there were 8 references to that domain in transient files, but all have been removed and Google still don't reinstate the ad's, however, they have used the same domain and allowed dynamic ads as approved? the person on the phone support won't let me speak to the tech team or provide any other information. This has been going on for over a week now and it takes 3 days to get a response from Google each time. None of the tools they provide are showing anything???

Answer (score 1):

This is not a WordPress question, but since I've dealt with this before here's a quick answer.

> Ensure that your site or application follows the guidelines above,
>   then you can request a review in the [Security Issues report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044101).

Source: [Malware and unwanted software](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249?hl=en)